# How to send numerical values to an input tag using Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I know this might be a repeated question but I tried various methods to solve this one but couldn't solve the situation

[image]
[image]

HTML code copied from the website

```
<input name="ctl00$TabContainer1$tpMain$ContentPlaceHolder1$Ins$txtDob" type="text" value="(dd/mm/yyyy)" maxlength="10" id="ctl00_TabContainer1_tpMain_ContentPlaceHolder1_Ins_txtDob" onselect="javascript:if(this.value=='(dd/mm/yyyy)') this.value='';this.style.color='';" onblur="javascript:InputValidation(this,'Date','Date of Birth','(dd/mm/yyyy)');" onclick="javascript:if(this.value=='(dd/mm/yyyy)') this.value='';this.style.color='';" onkeydown="return autodate(this)" onchange="javascript:CheckChanges();" onkeypress="return onlyNumbersWithForwardslash();" style="width:90%;" tabindex="0">
```

My code goes like this

```
string dob = startDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string[] array = dob.Split(new string[] { "/" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
char[] Chararray = string.Join(string.Empty, array).ToCharArray();

IWebElement DobElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_TabContainer1_tpMain_ContentPlaceHolder1_Ins_txtDob']")); // .Id("ctl00_TabContainer1_tpMain_ContentPlaceHolder1_Ins_txtDob"));
    DobElement.Clear();

    foreach (char s in Chararray)
    {
         int num = Int32.Parse(s.ToString());
         DobElement.SendKeys(""+num);
    }
```

anyone help is appreciated to input numerical numbers to the textbox

Comment: What is your question here? _anyone help_ in what? Where are you stuck? Error stack trace?

Comment: @DebanjanB there is no error throwing up numbers are not being inputted in to the textbox

Comment: You need to update the question with text based HTML instead of a picture.

Comment: @DebanjanB copied the html code also here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element, so to send a *chracter sequence* within the `<input>` field you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- *CssSelector*:

  ```
  IWebElement DobElement = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[id$='_Ins_txtDob'][name$='txtDob'][onblur*='InputValidation')]"));
  DobElement.Click();
  DobElement.Clear();
  DobElement.SendKeys(""+num);
  ```
- *XPath*:

  ```
  IWebElement DobElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@id, '_Ins_txtDob') and contains(@name, 'txtDob')][contains(@onblur, 'InputValidation')]"));
  DobElement.Click();
  DobElement.Clear();
  DobElement.SendKeys(""+num);
  ```

Comment: @DebenjanB could you explain the code why to include the onBlur but not other events like keypress, keydown

Comment: As you pointed out, virtually we could have considered `onkeydown` or `onkeypress` just like `onblur`. But if you observe the `onkeydown` event it's pretty generic and can be present for majority of the `<input>` elements. Same goes for `onkeypress`. Both of the alternatives should work. I choose to pick `onblur` as this _event_ will be the last event among the three events to be fired which may be the last _event_ to be rendered within the _HTML_.